# Node.js - are setTimeout callbacks fired in the same order as registered?

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, event-loop

I was wondering whether node.js guarantees the execution order of "expired" (ready to be executed) callbacks scheduled via `setTimeout`. The [manual](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/) seems to claim that the Timers phase of the event loop has a FIFO queue of callbacks.

Taking this into account in the example below, I expected that node schedules the first callback and after 1 second the remaining two in the order as specified in the code. Now, when the first callback fires, the execution "stops" for 5 seconds which means that when the callback returns, the other two are ready to be executed as well.

However, when I run the example, the output seems to be `first, third, second`. Strangely, when the delay time of the second callback is modified to, e.g., `2001` instead of `2000`, the order is as expected, i.e., `first, second, third`. Is this behavior by design?

```
const spawnSync = require('child_process').spawnSync;

function wait(delta){
    spawnSync('sleep', [delta]);
}

setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('first');
    wait(5);
}, 2000);

wait(1);

setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('second');
}, 2000);

setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('third');
}, 4000);
```

Comment: Is the output consistent or it changes over-time based on the same parameters

Comment: i guess if you execute this code for many times and / or on another machine you will get different behaviour due to JavaScripts `asynchronously` behaviour

Comment: This may help `A timer specifies the threshold after which a provided callback may be executed rather than the exact time a person wants it to be executed. Timers callbacks will run as early as they can be scheduled after the specified amount of time has passed; however, Operating System scheduling or the running of other callbacks may delay them.`

Comment: @yueyou the output seems to be consistent - I understand that the delay time is a lower bound on the execution delay of the callback, nevertheless if it is a FIFO queue, the order should be respected?

Answer (score 2):

After a closer inspection of the callback scheduling implementation in Node, it does indeed seem that the order of the `second`/`third` callbacks in the posted example is not really guaranteed.

The reason for this is how Node handles `setTimeout` callbacks in `lib/timers.js`. In short, these callbacks are stored in linked lists grouped by their corresponding delay time. Now, if one callback fires, Node determines its group, marks current time `t_now` and processes all callbacks within the group. For each one, it knows its registration time `t_reg` (when it was registered via `setTimeout`) and delay time `delta`. If `t_now - t_reg >= delta`, it invokes the callback. The thing is that `t_now` is evaluated only once for the entire group of callbacks corresponding to the same delay time.

To illustrate this, I compiled Node in debug mode (`--debug` option of `./configure` script) and executed the example as:

```
NODE_DEBUG=timer node ./example.js
```

On my machine, I get the following:

```
TIMER 38963: no 2000 list was found in insert, creating a new one
TIMER 38963: no 4000 list was found in insert, creating a new one
TIMER 38963: timeout callback 2000
TIMER 38963: now: 2069
TIMER 38963:    _idleStart = 64
first
TIMER 38963:    _idleStart = 1074
TIMER 38963: 2000 list wait because diff is 995
TIMER 38963: timeout callback 4000
TIMER 38963: now: 7075
TIMER 38963:    _idleStart = 1074
third
TIMER 38963: 4000 list empty
TIMER 38963: timeout callback 2000
TIMER 38963: now: 7076
TIMER 38963:    _idleStart = 1074
second
TIMER 38963: 2000 list empty
```

Here, we see that the `first` and `second` callbacks were scheduled at times `t1=64` and `t2=1074`, respectively. When the `first` callback is ready to fire at time `T=2069`, it takes more or less 5 seconds to execute it. Once this
execution finishes, Node continues within the same group of callbacks (i.e., callbacks associated with the same delay time) thus checking the `second` callback. However, it takes into account as current time not the time after the execution of the `first` callback but the time `T` when it started processing the callbacks (entered the `listOnTimeout` function in `lib/timers.js`). On my machine, since the `second` callback was registered at time `1074`, `2069 - 1074` is less than the delay time of `2000` and thus the `second` callback is not executed but rescheduled instead for later with delay time of `995` (however, with respect to the current time, not with respect to `T`).

To be more specific, since the `first` callback fires, we know that `T - t1 >= delta`. However, the relationship between `T - t2` and `delta` is not guaranteed. To illustrate this, if I remove the `wait(1)` call, I get:

```
TIMER 39048: no 2000 list was found in insert, creating a new one
TIMER 39048: no 4000 list was found in insert, creating a new one
TIMER 39048: timeout callback 2000
TIMER 39048: now: 2067
TIMER 39048:    _idleStart = 66
first
TIMER 39048:    _idleStart = 67
second
TIMER 39048: 2000 list empty
TIMER 39048: timeout callback 4000
TIMER 39048: now: 7080
TIMER 39048:    _idleStart = 67
third
TIMER 39048: 4000 list empty
```

So now, the `second` callback is scheduled at `t2=67`, i.e., `2` units of time later than the `first` callback. Now when `first` fires at time `T=2067`, Node processes the entire group of callbacks associated with delay time of `2000` as mentioned above thus proceeding to the `second` callback - in this case, `T-t2` is exactly equal to `2000` so that `second` is "luckily" fired as well. However, were the scheduling of the `second` callback delayed by mere `1` unit (due to for example some extraneous function call before invoking `setTimeout`), the `third` callback would fire sooner.

Answer (score 0):

From the  [docs](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/timers-in-node/)

> The timeout interval that is set cannot be relied upon to execute after that exact number of milliseconds. This is because other executing code that blocks or holds onto the event loop will push the execution of the timeout back. The only guarantee is that the timeout will not execute sooner than the declared timeout interval.

I think your example is demonstrating all these points, moreso the one around the fact that timers can be pushed back. It would appear to me that the calls to `spawnSync` are delaying the timers just enough to cause the overlap - presumably if you reduced the delay of the `wait` call in the first `setInterval` or increase the timeout of the last `setInterval` you’d see a more consistent behaviour.

Comment: But I have the same question as the question poster  `if it is a FIFO queue, the order should be respected?`

Comment: @yueyou my best guess would be callbacks are pushed onto the queue when they are ready to be fired and not when they’re *scheduled* to be - hence why *”the timeout interval that is set cannot be relied upon to execute after that exact number of milliseconds”*

Comment: Maybe this is the case. I think it will be better to dive deeper into it to see from the source

Comment: @James *calls to spawnSync are delaying the timers just enough to cause the overlap* - that was in fact the point of the question, to understand how the scheduling of the callbacks works in this "overlapping" scenario...

Comment: @ewcz in fairness, that's not what you asked :)

Comment: @James ah, sorry, I see that my question was perhaps too convoluted - the community doesn't seem to share the opinion, but I found quite interesting why the second callback fires after the third even though it was supposed to be executed 1 second earlier (especially since the manual mentions that the callbacks should be ordered on a FIFO principle), i.e., to understand the relative order of execution rather than the absolute timings...